# element groups inside a div css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, formatting, element

lets say i want to create web page using bootstraps grid layout. I have created boxes with different background colours and some text. Is there a way to define css properties like this for example?

HTML

```
<div class="blue">
<h1>Hello</h1>
<p>Some text</p>
</div>

<div class="red">
<h1>Hello again</h1>
<p>Some more text</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.blue {background-color: blue;color:black;
       .h1 {color:red;}
       .h4 {color:brown;}
}

.red {background-color: red;color:black;
        .h1 {color:blue;}
        .h4 {color:green;}
}
```

So when i create div with **blue class** i have **h1 red** and **h4 brown**  and for **class red** **h1 is blue** and **h4 is green** without the need to format anything else?

Comment: That's exactly what you've done. What's the question?

Comment: So this will work?My code is bit more complex so maybe i have a typo somewhere :(

Comment: Post what you've tried in a fiddle please if it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
.blue {
    background-color: blue;
    color:black;
}
    .blue h1 {
        color:red;
    }
    .blue h4 {
        color:brown;
    }

.red {
    background-color: red;
    color:black;
}
    .red h1 {
        color:blue;
    }
    .red h4 {
        color:green;
    }
```

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/dmBBDgdScQ)

If you want to do it the way you had it:

```
.blue {
    h1 {/* */}
    h4 {/* */}
}

.red {
    h1{/* */}
    h4{/* */}
}
```

Then you need to look at [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) which will let you do that.

In standard CSS, you can't put styles under the same 'group'.

You have to have a new line for each different element you want to style.

I usually find it easier if I'm using pure CSS to style my it like this:

```
.blue {
  /* style here */
}

    .blue p {
        /* .blue p styles */
    }


        .blue p a {
            /* .blue p a styles */
        }
```

and so on. The 'deeper' you get, the more indented. That means I can easily manage my styles for normal css.

Comment: Oooh yes thats what i was looking for, i completely forgot about this. Thank you very much

Comment: No worries, glad I could help! @Houdasek

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
.blue {background-color: blue;color:black;}
      .blue h1 {color:red;}
       .blue h4 {color:brown;}


.red {background-color: red;color:black;}
        .red h1 {color:blue;}
        .red h4 {color:green;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
.blue {
    background-color: blue;
    color:black;
}
.blue h1 {
    color:red;
}
.blue h4 {
    color:brown;
}
.red {
    background-color: red;
    color:black;
}
.red h1 {
    color:blue;
}
.red h4 {
    color:green;
}
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ghqLzwmb/) with bootstrap formatted rows.